# Pass variables into a Flash movie from HTML

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flashvars

As a Flash newbie I found this very confusing and it cost me a couple of hours.  Answering my own question here in case anyone has the same problem.

Technically you should be able to do something like this:

```
<param name="movie" value="movie.swf?param=value" />
<embed src="movie.swf?param=value" ...
```

Or this:

```
<PARAM NAME "FlashVars" VALUE="param=value">
<EMBED .... FlashVars="param=value">
```

Both should create a variable in the _root or _level0 scope called 'param' with the correct value.

These are documented [here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/index.html)

However, in my particular version of Flash (CS4, ActionScript 2.0), this didn't work.

Comment: Could you post your specific HTML and Actionscript code?  Flashvars is a great way to get data into your Flash app, and everything you've said is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which worked for me is to modify the AC_FL_RunContent() function in the HTML generated by CS4, adding the parameters which need to be passed to the movie, e.g.

```
'flashvars', 'param=value',
```

It seems this function overwrites anything which is directly specified in the OBJECT and EMBED tags or on the query string.

There may be better solutions out there...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use *ExternalInterface* to call a JavaScript function on the HTML page that returns a value. This has the added value that you don't have to hardcode the value and you can pass parameters to the JavaScript function.

In the Flash Movie:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function getOutsideValue(argToJS:String):Void {
 var jsArgument:String = argToJS;
 var result:Object = ExternalInterface.call("stringAdd", jsArgument);
}
```

In the Javascript in the HTML page:

```
function stringAdd(inptStr){
 var strToAdd = inptStr;
 strToAdd += " added text";
 return strToAdd;
}
```

So when you call the ActionScript function in Flash:

```
getOutsideValue("I get");
```

It will return:

```
I get added text
```

Note that ExternalInterface can also be used to call functions inside the Flash from JavaScript. Examples of both can be found here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html

It seems that this is the recommended way to passing information to and from SWF movies, it certainly is more dynamic and powerful than just using hard coded values.